# Не вытаскиваем значение переменной, перезаписанной в AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Опытные программисты, подскажите, пожалуйста, почему переменная yaPrice отказывается перезаписываться в функции AJAX. Причем при вызове в консоле браузера показывает корректное значение, но document.querySelector('.yandexprice').innerHTML = yaPrice; и дальнейший код это игнорирует

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

var yandexPrice = document.createElement('p');
yandexPrice.className = 'yandexprice';
document.body.appendChild(yandexPrice );
yandexPrice.style.display="none";

var yaPrice = null;

var regExp=/<td class="pageHeading"\salign="right"\svalign="top">\S+/;
$.ajax({ url: 'https://solisunshop.ru/constant-delight/balzam-posle-britja-barber-care-200ml-p-197549.html?ukr=1&rus=1&currency=RUR',

success: function(data) {yaPrice=(regExp.exec(data)[0].replace(/[^0-9]/gim, ""))}
});
document.querySelector('.yandexprice').innerHTML = yaPrice;

window.dataLayer.push({
        'ecommerce' : {
            'currencyCode': 'RUB',
            'detail' : {
                'products' : [
                    {
                     'name' : document.URL.toString(),
                     'price': yaPrice
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что обработчик `success` будет выполнен после того, как будет получен ответ от сайта solisunshop.ru, а `document.querySelector('.yandexprice').innerHTML = yaPrice;` в момент загрузки скрипта.

Перенесите код, использующий переменную `yaPrice` внутрь обработчика:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://solisunshop.ru/constant-delight/balzam-posle-britja-barber-care-200ml-p-197549.html?ukr=1&rus=1&currency=RUR',
  success: function(data) {
    yaPrice=(regExp.exec(data)[0].replace(/[^0-9]/gim, ""));
    document.querySelector('.yandexprice').innerHTML = yaPrice;
    ...
  }
});
```

Comment: Вы мне очень помогли, моё почтение. :)

Comment: @Артём [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).